# Image preloading with javascript in iOS

Tags: javascript, html, ios, cordova

### Scenario

I use two images namely 'car-light.png' and 'car-dark.png'. When user touches the image, which was car-light.png, it becomes car-dark.png.

Here is the code I used.

```
<img src="car-light.png" id="car" ontouchstart="changeCar()">
```

In changeCar(), I wrote this code

```
$("#car").attr('src','url(car-dark.png)');
```

### Question

Is there a way to speed this up by preloading the image? Or am I making too big a deal with fast loading time? If it is the case where pre-loading is necessary, is the following code correct?

```
var img1 = new Image();
img1.src = "car-dark.png";

function changeCar(imgName) 
{
    document[imgName] = img1;
}
```

and in HTML

```
<img src="car-light.png" name="car" ontouchstart="changeCar('car')">
```

Answer (score 1):

Putting this somewhere in your startup JS code will preload the image:

```
var img1 = new Image();
img1.src = "car-dark.png";
```

This will cause the image to be in the browser cache so it will load quickly if you use it later on in the action of the page.  You could use the img1 object directly, but often it's easier to just use the URL and let the browser fetch the image from it's memory cache like this:

```
<img src="car-light.png" id="car" ontouchstart="changeCar()">

function changeCar() {
    $("#car").attr('src','car-dark.png');
}
```

Comment: I added the first two lines inside onBodyLoad(). However, the $("#car").attr('src','car-dark.png') returned a ? instead of the image. Shouldn't there be a url(car-dark.png)? Also, what is the point of creating img1 image object then?

Comment: The first two lines of javascript should get executed immediately as the page loads (you do not need to wait for the page to load to execute them).  This line of JS `$("#car").attr('src','car-dark.png');` would get executed some time later in responding to some user action.  You do not use `url()` around it unless that is some special function in your app.  It is not a standard so I am not familiar with it or why it would be used.